# CoffeeScript + Client side HAML/SLIM-like templating?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, template-engine, slim-lang

I have a project in Rails 4 which uses Slim (http://www.slim-lang.com/) template engine. Super awesome! But in the end because my app is more client-side heavy I still have tonns of nasty HTML that I want to abandon in favor of something like Slim for CoffeeScript.

Is there such thing? I've found http://coffeekup.org/ and couple of Jade-CoffeeScript variations, but they all look to be dead.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked out Sinatra? http://www.sinatrarb.com/ You can maintain your ruby code base, use Haml, and include Coffeescript, and whatever other libraries you wish easily.

Comment: @kunalbhat: He's looking for a client-side template system that, presumably, is like Slim but uses CoffeeScript instead of Ruby.

Comment: you mean like https://github.com/Nami-Doc/nephrite, only actually good ?